# SSIS Script Task throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to query the database and send the content in the body of the email. When I try to run the package it throws deadlock error. Can anyone please suggest what is that I am missing

Script is like below

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;
#endregion

namespace ST_c074d0acfee7488b96d42a0f858efee7
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        }

        public void Main()
        {
            Variables varCollection = null;

            string User_Recepient_Email_ID = Dts.Variables["User::UserEml"].Value.ToString();

            //Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::EmailData");
            //Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);
            var data = varCollection["User::EmailData"].Value;

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt, varCollection["User::EmailData"].Value);

            SendMailMessage("loadJob@xyz.com", User_Recepient_Email_ID, "ETL Load Status Report", ConvertDataTableToHTML(dt), true, "smtp.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.org");

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }


        public static string ConvertDataTableToHTML(DataTable dt)
        {
            string html = "<table border ='1'>";
            //add header row
            html += "<tr>";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                html += "<th>" + dt.Columns[i].ColumnName + "</th>";
            html += "</tr>";
            //add rows
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                html += "<tr style='color:blue;'>";
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                    html += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i][j].ToString() + "</td>";
                html += "</tr>";
            }
            html += "</table>";
            return html;
        }
        private void SendMailMessage(string From, string SendTo, string Subject, string Body, bool IsBodyHtml, string Server)
        {
            MailMessage htmlMessage;
            SmtpClient mySmtpClient;

            htmlMessage = new MailMessage(From, SendTo, Subject, Body);
            htmlMessage.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml;

            mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(Server);
            mySmtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            mySmtpClient.Send(htmlMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the

[image]

And the package looks like below.. For every user I need to get all the order and order details and send it to them as email. SO I have the script within the Loop

[image]

Earlier I was getting deadlock error and I changed few things referring to different articles and now I am getting below error

```
Error: 0x1 at Script Task: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Task failed: Script Task
Warning: 0x80019002 at Foreach Loop each User: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
Warning: 0x80019002 at SurplusMouse_EmailOrderDetail: SSIS Warning Code DTS_W_MAXIMUMERRORCOUNTREACHED.  The Execution method succeeded, but the number of errors raised (1) reached the maximum allowed (1); resulting in failure. This occurs when the number of errors reaches the number specified in MaximumErrorCount. Change the MaximumErrorCount or fix the errors.
SSIS package
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the code and you will get a much better error. That error can be anything really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that this is your error (varCollection is null and you are referencing something that is null):

```
var data = varCollection["User::EmailData"].Value;
```

Assign it just like you did the line before...

```
var data = Dts.Variables["User::EmailData"].Value;
```

However, I think you are trying this. Email Data is a recordset stored in an object. this is the logic you want for that.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;

DataTable dt= new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::emailData"].Value);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   //insert what you want to do here
}
```